# Multiple array controllers inside an Object controller Ember

Tags: ember.js, nsarraycontroller

I've a template whose model contains two different sets of array elements. I've to list them with a check box, so that user can select multiple items from both the lists. I've to collect all the items.

I started as follows

```
    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="temp">
        <p>List 1</p>
        <ul>
            {{#each list1}}
                <li>
                    {{input type="checkbox"}}
                    {{name}}
                </li>
            {{/each}}
        </ul>
        <p>List 2</p>
        <ul>
            {{#each list2}}
                <li>
                    {{input type="checkbox"}}
                    {{name}}
                </li>
            {{/each}}
        </ul>
    </script>
```

I thought to have controllers for the two lists separately. But not sure how to get the list together. The place where I've the total control could be "TempController", but not sure how to get the checked property of each item in the two different lists.

I hope I've explained my functionality. Hope there is a solution or work around for this.

Thanks.